# Using If then else in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi i am a newbie to use MySql statements.

This is my Parent table

```
Name   Sell_amt   Mrp_amt    Cost_amt   Goods_Name           Goods_Weight   Goods_quantity
John       100         90         80         Choclate            1lb               5
samson     100         110        60         mobile              0.5lb             8
James      100         100        70         chair               1lb               5
```

This is my Child table columns

```
 
Name   Sell_amt   Mrp_amt    Special_DealStatus
```

Now i need to update the child table based on my parent table.
The problem is If (Sell_amt'<'Mrp_amt) then i need to update Special_DealStatus  column with 1.

Please suggest,I have googled a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Oops wrong link, try this one: Have a look at the [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression.

Answer (score 1):

I created a SQL fiddle for you to try out. What you are looking for is this

```
INSERT INTO Child_Table (`name`, `sellamt`, `mrpamt`, `specialdealstatus`)
SELECT name, sellamt, mrpamt,1
FROM Parent_Table
WHERE sellamt < mrpamt;
```

here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2966b/1)

What this does is inserts the selected values from the Parent_Table into the the Child_Table WHERE sellamt < mrpamt as you asked. It also sets specialdealstatus to one with a static value '1' placed into the SELECT statement.

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class MysqlPreparedStatement
    {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        try
        {
          // create a mysql database connection
          String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
          String mySqlServer = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
          Class.forName(myDriver);
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(mySqlServer, "root", "");

      // the mysql statement
      String query = " INSERT INTO Child_Table (`name`, `sellamt`, `mrpamt`,  `specialdealstatus`)
    SELECT name, sellamt, mrpamt,1
    FROM Parent_Table
    WHERE sellamt < mrpamt ";

    // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
 // execute the preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.execute();

          conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Throwing an exception!");
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The Java is an added bonus, because you are new. Next time please include code you have already tried or worked on to show you have put some effort into the issue. I didn't do this with my first question, so I suppose I am paying it forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following with case as Andreas already mentioned.

```
insert into Child
select Name,Sell_amt,Mrp_amt, case when sell_amt<Mrp_amt then 1 else null end as Special_DealStatus from Parent
```